# Which software packages would allow my RPi to alert me to mentions on "The Bakery" RPi chatroom?

Tags: raspbian, connection, web-browsers

I make use of the chat-room facilities provided on Stack Exchange, in particular I visit the main one specifically for the Raspberry Pi, i.e. "[The Bakery](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery)".  It is  possible to be notified when someone addresses or targets a message to someone who has been there (recently I believe) - I would like to automate this to make an electronic "ear-burner" as it were to flash an LED (well drive the Pin up and down for say 1 second high every 20 seconds for an hour after a mention of my identity) on a free GPIO pin!

At present I am using the Iceweasel browser on my Debian desktop and there  is a version for the Raspbian RPi that I have installed - I am using FireFox sync and I have just done that for the RPi.  Besides that what would I need to put onto a Pi so that it could listen out for messages/mentions that are targeted to me and alert me when that happens? I have [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) but I do not think it can communicate beyond the browser (cannot read/write a file or pipe that an interface to the hardware would need).

---

EDIT:  The issue here I feel that does make it RPi relevant even if not total RPi specific is the linkage of content on a Web-page, which is not something that the user has authorship or control over, to something OUTSIDE of the web-browser.  For very good reasons, things like JavaScript are sand-boxed, so that they cannot affect the local machine that the browser is running on - I think that things like "greasemonkey" may help a little here but I can't see how!  The sort of situation I conceive needs to "climb out of the sand-box" (under carefully scripted conditions, of course) I want some way for a "chat mention" to trigger a response in the RPi's hardware - but fundamentally I cannot see how that can come about without the ability to "write" to a local "file" or more likely a "pipe" to a daemon that can respond and change the state of a GPIO pin as required.

Whilst my particular idea is for targeting the RPi SE Chat page - the general concept of controlling the local hardware from the confines of a browser has a wider application in the RPi environment I am sure.

Comment: This might come in handy (once you've sorted out all the other *engineering problems*): http://space.stackexchange.com/a/12622

Comment: The android app on my tablet sounds a tone when this happens (at least for the main site - it may also for the bakery). You may also want to check the SO API and roll your own.

Comment: This may help as well http://stackapps.com/

Comment: My PC browser also makes that tone - it is part of the JS for the chat page that retrieves and plays "//cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/se.mp3" - so it is using a remote resource and utilising audio capabilities built-in to the browser - not sure that that is something I could hook into... 8-(